# Django pasar parametro no funciona

Tags: python, django

espero puedan ayudarme, estoy tratando de hacer una función en la cual pasando el parámetro pueda renderizar diferente template pero no se que es lo que esta fallando si las vistas o las url, alguien me ayuda?

views.

```
def hola(request, par):
    #val = val
    pregunta = Datos_usuario_DB.objects.all().order_by('-id').filter(activo="1")[:15]
    respuesta = Datos_respuesta_DB.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:15]
    preguntarespuesta = zip(pregunta, respuesta)
    #pregunta2 = [{'nombre':'hh'},{'nombre':'hhsss'}]
    plantilla = {'': 'index.html', 'nosotros': 'nosotros.html', 'contacto': 'contacto.html'}
    return render(request, plantilla['%s' % par], {'preguntarespuesta': preguntarespuesta})
    #return HttpResponse(val)
```

urls

```
url(r'^[a-z\.-]+$', views.hola, name='hola'),
```

Comment: Cual es el problema que tienes?, el parametro no lo recibe la función? no llamas al template que quieres si no a otro? obtienes un 404? tienes un error de reversecall!?. Saludos

Comment: Obtengo un 404, en teoría debería de renderizar cualquiera de esos templates poniendo /contacto o / nosotros o index /

Comment: si llamas a una de ellas directamente funciona? Y con esa misma plantilla que si funciona directamente, si 'plantilla['%s' % par]' lo igualas a una variable y pasas esa variable al render funciona?

Comment: Creo que deberías formular tu pregunta. No se entiende si estas hablando de los parámetros de tu función hola o si estas hablando de como renderizar distintos templates.

Answer (score 0):

Tu url está mal definida. No definiste el nombre de tu parametro en la url. Quizas podés revisar el [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.11/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views). Pero más allá de eso, creo que lo que tu quieres es algo así:

```
url(r'^(?P<par>[a-z\.-]+)/$', views.hola, name='hola'),
```